# asp .net session variable storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, session-variables

Where are session variables such as...

`Session["TestVariable"]`

...stored?

I've used them in the past quite a lot - but I don't understand where/how long they are stored for. I'm impressed by how they can be accessed by any page or any class but yet don't understand where they reside.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Session in Asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229228/session-in-asp-net)

Comment: @vcsjones - wrong. "When we add a variable to ASP.NET Session, where are those variables actually stored on the client side?" That question is incorrect in itself, mine is not. Mine may be a duplicate, as you say, but not of the question found on the link you provided.

Comment: The question is more-or-less the same, but if you want a completely identical question, then [look at this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526349/where-are-the-session-variables-saved) - your question is a subset of that one. My point is that this question has been asked plenty of times before.

Comment: Whether it's more-or-less the same is debatable. Either way, thanks for the links to the other question, I'll have a read now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on how you have session configured, but if it's normal `InProc` session it's stored in the memory space of the ASP.NET worker process.

Take a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) on session state for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer James, makes sense, thanks for the link too.

Answer (score -2):

It is storied on the server side cache per user, that is why it is available after page reload. You might want to [look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) for a better overview.